# Iphone app style count down improvement?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, sdk, countdowntimer

I've been searching internet for a few days till now. I did find some useful information but just want to make things perfect.

I'm trying to write a countdown app which only uses second, my current code is a bit too complex and maybe off the main road. Looking for someone who can straight it up.

```
- (void)updateTimer{

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"s"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];

// where the part change time string back to int
NSString *changeToInt = timeString;
int stringInt = [changeToInt integerValue];

// loop for count down numbers
if ((buttValue - stringInt) > 0) {
    leftTime = buttValue - stringInt;
    [self updateValue];
} else {
    leftTime = 0;
    [self updateValue];
}
```

}

2 problems with the code, 1) do I have to go through all the date formatting to get a integer? 2) in the loop I used two variables, I was hoping to take one out and use something like --

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you need exactly, but I think that you just want to get the number of seconds from now to a known date. The timeIntervalSinceNow method will give you a NSInteger value that represent the number of seconds from the receiver date until now, which, if the receiver is earlier than now, will be a negative value (otherwise it will be positive).

So, just to be more explicit:

```
- (void)updateTimer
{
    leftTime = MAX(0, -[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]); //if less than 0 will be forced to 0 -> date reached
    [self updateValue];
}
```

As I said, I'm not sure this is what you want. If it's not, I am sorry.
Good luck!

Comment: I'm such a fool, i didn't understand how scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval work. I now changed the code to    - `(void)updateTimer{
       
    // loop for invert count down numbers
    if ((buttValue - 1) > 0) {
        buttValue = buttValue - 1;
        [self updateValue];
    } else {
        buttValue = 0;
        [self updateValue];
        [timer invalidate];
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)initialiseTimer
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeElapsed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    startDate = [[NSDate date] retain];

}
-(void)timeElapsed
{

    NSLog(@"Seconds elapsed since start date %d", abs([startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]));

}
```

you can manipulate it to make a count down style app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code !!

```
-(IBAction)startAndStop:(id)sender
{
    startDate = [[NSDate date]retain];
    if([btnStopWatch.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"])
    {
        stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/100.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [btnStopWatch setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if([btnStopWatch.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Stop"])
    {
        [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
        [btnStopWatch setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
- (void)updateTimer
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;
    NSLog(@"Seconds elapsed since start date %d", abs([startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]));

}
```